# Wifi extender fluctuates at certain time of day

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a netgear wifi extender for over 5 years. In recent months, I notice one thing really weird. Starting late afternoon, it gets very bumpy: keeps dropping connection or the speed becomes very slow. It normally lasts 1 - 2 hours, sometimes longer.

I already confirmed the following:

1. It has the latest firmware. I actually did not do any firmware update. It is either it updates itself or there is no update in the last 5 years.
2. When the problem happens at this wifi extender, there is no problem at the wifi router in another room. This router is also a cable modem and it is the main network entrance to my home.
3. It is not because my family are changing our network connections. In fact, I am the primary user of this extender most of the time and I was not doing anything new when I observe the problem.
4. I also notice the problem at some other times, like night time or weekend. But seems late afternoon is more common.
5. There is a reset button at the extender, I guess it does the power down and power up when pressing twice. It sometimes can fix the problem, but not a reliable solution.

Any suggestion how to fix this problem? Or what else to check?

**EDIT**
There is no usage change when the problem happens. As said, I am the primary user of this extender and I use it for work. So the sudden usage change such as TV, streaming, video, etc. can be excluded.

Comment: Wi-Fi Extenders suffer from reduced bandwidth because of reverse traffic from Extender back to host to service the Extender.  That said, is your TV hooked up to wireless; are you streaming movies or other TV on your laptop. Updates are not daily but should be checked.

Comment: Could be an "external source" interfering on the frequency. Does accessing the WiFi without the extender resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Move to a new location with no close neighbours..

Seriously though, this sounds **exactly** like I would expect if I have neighbours who use WIFI and their kids cone home from school.    Realise that WIFI bandwidth is a very limited, uncontrolled, shared resource, and that unless carefully managed usage of WIFI of unrelated third parties can affect your connection.

WIFI repeaters are horrible technology - while they do work, they create/compound a tragedy of the commons by wasting (doubling) the amount of signal used in order to extend it.

Solutions/mitigations include replacing the repeater with an AP client (which will requirecan Ethernet or similar connection to the cap client), using Ethernet over power, moving into the 5 gig (AC) band as much as possible (this band has a lot more bandwidth but less range). The best solution from a tech POV, however, is to work with your neighbours to build a managed, structured network at both locations such that you don't have overlapping frequencies and make the most of your bandwidth.